# How to write sublime text snippet to make setters and getters and instance variable for ruby?

Tags: ruby, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I want to learn how to create snippets for future, and want a snippet that can create setter and getter for instance variable in Ruby files.

Something like this

```
name:= {TAB KEY}
```

it becomes like this

```
def name=(n)
    @name = n
end
def name 
    @name 
end
```

Comment: You should be using `attr_accessor` instead. The easiest way would be to do it with [macros](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/macros.html?highlight=macro).

Comment: hi, macros sort of work but i've to assign a shortcut to it, instead of having macro trigger if i type certain things like `name::-`

Answer (score 2):

Its pretty useless to create getters and setters with snippets for ruby.
Using `attr_accessor` & `attr_reader` is the fastest and cleanest way to declare these properties and NOT having to create snippets for it.

```
attr_accessor :name
```

is the same as

```
def name 
 @name
end

def name=(n)
 @name = n
end
```

99% of the time this is what you want. Just declare an attribute accessor for the given instance variable.

The remaining 1% is when you actually want a custom attribute with some extra validations inside. And even then you could declare

```
attr_reader :custom_attribute

def custom_attribute=(value)
  # some validation code here ...
  @custom_attribute = value
end
```

Comment: omg i think i saw it somewhere, thanks for sharing this. But just in case i still want snippet thing